# Missing maven plugin in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded the eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 version. I referred many of the posts sample given below.

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute.

**Says that Kepler version already have maven plugin.But in this version i didn't find the maven plugin**. Please help me to create/import maven projects in this version of eclipse.

Getting the error if i tried to install it from **eclipse market place or from install new software**.

The installation cannot be completed as requested.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20150413-2215)
Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.0.20140606-0033) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.1.20150109-1820 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.1.20150109-1820) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.2.20150413-2215) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.5.0.20140606-0033)
To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.5.0,1.6.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.1.20150109-1820 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.5.1.20150109-1820)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, is there a reason why you're using the Kepler release? That's 2 major releases behind.

Regardless of the version, whether or not m2e is pre-installed into your Eclipse depends on what *package* you downloaded; some of the packages include it and others do not. The two most popular packages that *do* include m2e are **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** and **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**.

Installing m2e from the update site (Install New Software) should work, too, but its error messages are difficult to decipher and diagnose.

Comment: I searched for the eclipse release, which should have maven in built. Instead of installing it externally. Suggest me in which version do we get it.I downloaded from [link](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2).Please suggest the link which should have the JAVAEE and maven packages pre installed. Thanks

Comment: Yes @E-Riz I downloaded the Java developer eclipse.Actually all i expected is available in Java EE eclipse plugin.Thanks for your reply.